# MYSQL PHP SYNTAX alias join

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, alias

I am trying to do a query on two tables doing a left join where there are common field names in the two tables. My fuzzy understanding is that MYSQL does not remember certain table initials so you are better off using an alias.  However, the following query is throwing an unknown column error on the alias muserid.

Would appreciate suggestions on how to fix.

```
$sql= "SELECT c.id as cid, c.*,m.userid as muserid
FROM `contacts` c
LEFT JOIN `mycontacts` m
ON cid = personid
WHERE muserid = '$userid' ";
```

Comment: When you are selecting `c.*` why do you have to select `c.id` again?

Answer (score 2):

This not about `JOIN`. In MySQL the `SELECT` statement is evaluated after the `WHERE` and `FROM` clause, there for you can't refer to an alias in the `WHERE` clause. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c.id as cid, c.*,m.userid as muserid
    FROM `contacts` c
    LEFT JOIN `mycontacts` m ON c.id = m.personid
) t
WHERE muserid = '$userid';
```

Here is the MySQL query execution order<sup>1</sup>:

> - FROM clause
> - WHERE clause
> - GROUP BY clause
> - HAVING clause
> - SELECT clause
> - ORDER BY clause.

<sup>**1:**<sup>[**MySQL query execution order**](http://nijumohan.com/mysql-query-execution-order/)</sup></sup>

Comment: Unknown column 'cid' in 'on clause'

Comment: This comment was posted on my answer earlier by the OS:

"there is something about it recognizes the initials of the first table but not the second or vice versa. – user1260310"

Comment: @user1260310 - Try `ON c.id = m.personid` instead, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Good catch on Mahmoud on the execution order precedence. Since @user1260310 want to use alias this question gets interesting. But if you decide to use initials, it works just fine.. * [Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8636/3)